# Fancybox 3, баг, при клике внутри окна дублируется еще одно

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Как запретить дублирование попап окна при клике в контентной области? Но, чтобы текст можно было выделять мышкой и кнопка закрыть работала.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#fancy-1').on('click', function() {
    $('[data-fancybox="gallery-1"]').fancybox({
      touch: false,
      toolbar: false,
      hash: false,
      //smallBtn: true,
      clickSlide: false,
      //thumbs: false,
      lang: "ru",
      i18n: {
        ru: {
          CLOSE: "Закрыть",
          NEXT: "Следующий",
          PREV: "Предыдущий",
          ERROR: "Ошибка"
        }
      }
    }).first().trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="fancy-1" class="btn btn-blue" href="javascript:;">Смотреть</a>
  <div id="popup-1" style="display: none;">
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
      <h1>1 Заголовок 1</h1>
      <p>Текст 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
      <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
      <p>Текст 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-fancybox="gallery-1">
      <h1>Заголовок 3</h1>
      <p>Текст 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А почему без этой: `}).first().trigger('click');` строчки не работает?

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин
Без этой строчки вообще ничего не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, спасибо большое разработчику fancybox за его помощь!

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#fancy-1').on('click', function() {
    $.fancybox.open( $('.inline-gallery-1'), {
      touch: false,
      toolbar: false,
      hash: false,
      clickSlide: false,
      lang: "ru",
      i18n: {
        ru: {
          CLOSE: "Закрыть",
          NEXT: "Следующий",
          PREV: "Предыдущий",
          ERROR: "Ошибка"
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <a id="fancy-1" class="btn btn-blue" href="javascript:;">Смотреть</a>

    <div id="popup-1" style="display: none;">
      <div class="inline-gallery-1">
        <h1>1 Заголовок 1</h1>
        <p>Текст 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-gallery-1">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <p>Текст 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-gallery-1">
        <h1>Заголовок 3</h1>
        <p>Текст 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```